# How to start Windows 10 Explorer at a specific screen location with a specific window size?

Tags: windows-explorer, positional-parameter

In Linux, I can do something like

> gnome-terminal --geometry=100x35+10+10

(gnome-terminal --geometry=widthxheight+Xposition+Yposition)

This is possible with many different linux applications.

Is there a similar way in Windows 10 to open and position explorer windows?
I am not talking aboout the default position and size, but setting the position and size per window.

I need to open several windows, each in another position and size and I would like to script this.
At the end i would have several "Workspaces" which I can start up as i need them..

Any hint?

Comment: What about referring to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979135/251671

Comment: See here for a program you can make on your computer *MoveWindow.exe* - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/movewindowexe-moves-window.html